# SPI Code Instability - Raspbian (Debian) Linux on RPi

Tags: c++, linux, raspbian, spi

I am trying to get my software to read and write writing a CAT25512 EEPROM from a Raspberry Pi 3 with Raspbian (Debian) Linux. Before writing to the memory a Write Enable Latch (WEL) has to be set with command 0x06. This write is successful. It is then checked with the read status register command 0x05, which also succeeds. Then the write, read, and successive status read commands get no response and/or fail.

I have tried adding some delays to wait for the HW. I have also restructured the code many times.

I apologize in advance for the complete file, but I'm not sure where the problem lies.

```
#include <stdint.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/spi/spidev.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

#define ARRAY_SIZE(a) (sizeof(a) / sizeof((a)[0]))
#define WAIT_FOR_EEPROM(a) do { for (int z=0; z<0x3FFF; z++); } while (eepromBusy((a) != 0x02));

const char *device = "/dev/spidev0.0";

uint8_t  mode=SPI_MODE_0;
uint8_t  bits=8;
uint32_t baud=500000;

uint8_t buffer[4] = {0};

int transfer(int spi_file, uint8_t* buffer, int length); // Prototype

int eepromBusy(int spi_file) {
        buffer[0] = 0x05;
        buffer[1] = 0x00;

        transfer(spi_file, buffer, 2);
        return (buffer[1]);
}

int main() {
        int fd = open(device,O_RDWR);
        if (fd < 0) printf("can't open device");

        int ret;
        ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_WR_MODE, &mode);
        if (ret == -1) printf("can't set spi mode");

        ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_WR_BITS_PER_WORD, &bits);
        if (ret == -1) printf("can't set bits!");

        ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_WR_MAX_SPEED_HZ, &baud);
        if (ret == -1) printf("can't set speed!");

        ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_RD_MODE, &mode);
        if (ret == -1) printf("can't set spi mode");

        ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_RD_BITS_PER_WORD, &bits);
        if (ret == -1) printf("can't set bits!");

        ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_RD_MAX_SPEED_HZ, &baud);
        if (ret == -1) printf("can't set speed!");

        printf("spi mode set as %u\n", mode);

        printf("bits per byte set as %u\n", bits);
        printf("max speed set at %u\n", baud);

        do {
                // Write Enable
                buffer[0] = 0x06;
                transfer(fd, buffer, 1);

                // Read Status
                buffer[0] = 0x05;
                buffer[1] = 0x00;
                transfer(fd, buffer, 2);
        } while (!(buffer[1] & 0x02));

        printf("Status Reg: %x\n", buffer[1]);

        WAIT_FOR_EEPROM(fd)

//      usleep(100);

        // Write Byte

        buffer[0] = 0x02;
        buffer[1] = 0x00;
        buffer[2] = 0x10;
        buffer[3] = 0xAA;
        transfer(fd, buffer, 4);

/*      uint8_t busy = -1;
        do {
                usleep(50);
                buffer[0] = 0x05;
                buffer[1] = 0x00;
                transfer(fd, buffer, 2);
            busy = buffer[1] & 0x01;
    } while (busy);
*/
        WAIT_FOR_EEPROM(fd)

        // Read Byte
        buffer[0] = 0x03;
        buffer[1] = 0x00;
        buffer[2] = 0x10;
        buffer[3] = 0x00;
        transfer(fd, buffer, 4);
        printf("Received byte: %i\n", buffer[3]);

        if (close(fd) > 0) printf("can't close device");

        return 0;
}

int transfer(int spi_file, uint8_t *buffer, int length) {
        //struct spi_ioc_transfer spi[length] = {0};
        int ret = -1;
        struct spi_ioc_transfer tr[length] = {0};

        for (int x=0; x<length; ++x) {
                tr[x].tx_buf            = (unsigned long)(buffer+x);
                tr[x].rx_buf            = (unsigned long)(buffer+x);
                tr[x].len               = sizeof(*(buffer+x));
                tr[x].delay_usecs       = 0;
                tr[x].speed_hz          = baud;
                tr[x].bits_per_word     = bits;
                tr[x].cs_change         = 0;
        };

        ret = ioctl(spi_file, SPI_IOC_MESSAGE(length), &tr);

        if (ret < 1) printf("Transfer Error!!! First Byte Was: 0x%x\n",         buffer[0]);

        return ret;
}
```

I am currently getting the `Transfer Error!!! First Byte Was: 0x5` error twice, indicating that the `WAIT_FOR_EEPROM(fd)` commands are not properly being executed.

In the beginning, the WEL bit is set with command 0x06 and the status is correctly reported as 2. The data read from EEPROM has read out as 0 or 211 depending on how I've tweaked the code. It should be 0xAA (170).

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Thanks, Mathias. I have seen both methods used in the transfer function and I have tried both. It seems to work both ways, which makes sense. I did manage to figure out why the transfer function was crashing. The issue lies in WAIT_FOR_EEPROM(a). `eepromBusy()` was receiving the argument `(a) != 0x02`, which is obviously a problem. It should be `while(eepromBusy(a) != 0x02)`.This change solves the transfer error, but more remains.

I am still having a problem where the EEPROM stops responding at the second `WAIT_FOR_EEPROM()`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the transfer() function is responsible to setup and execute one SPI command per call.
Why you are using an array of 'struct spi_ioc_transfer' ?
Why are you loop over the number of bytes in buffer and setup a 'spi_ioc_transfer' structure for each ?

Take a look at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/raspberrypi/linux/rpi-3.10.y/Documentation/spi/spidev_test.c